# Appium XCUIElement showing the same displayed text in accessibility id, value, name, label

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I've started using Appium for iOS app automation. The developers had put the ids and name to every element in the app code to assist the automation engineers, however, when I inspect it using Appium it doesn't show any of them. It shows only the same displayed text in accessibility id, value, name, label.

What should I ask developer so that those id and names can be used for automation using Appium.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the developer to set the accessibility id for the elements.

My advice is that you should also ask the developer to change the accessibility id to something that is not exactly the value of the element, for example: if you have a button that says "Open", some devs will just give it the id "Open". You should ask them to set the accessibility id as "open" or even "openID" - in this way you can make sure that all the elements have an accessibility ID and you can easily spot missing ID's and ask the developer to add them.

Answer (score 1):

In ios whatever the value given to the label of an element that will become the accessibility id of the element.Accessibility id is simply nothing but the text visible on the screen.In the example shown above the name or label will be the accessibility id of the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.ID(“Drive”)).click();
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId(“Drive”).click();
driver.findElement(By.name(“Drive”)).click();
driver.findElementByName(“Drive”).click();
```

In the above example "Drive" may be the label or name.
Appium will first search for an accessibility id that matches. If there is none found, a string match will be attempted on the element labels. Finally, if the id passed in is a localization key, it will search the localized string.

Just ask your developers to give label to every element and that label will become the accessibility id of that particular element.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience I learned that, Identifier field is necessary to provide accessiblity/ name attribute to the element in iOS app.

Then you can identify elements with

```
@iOSFindBy(accessibility = "myid")
public MobileElement SOME_OBJECT;
```

Or

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("myid")
```

Note: Providing any value to Label field will override the actual value displayed on the screen. So, generally avoid to provide any value to the Label field. This will ensure that, we'll be able to fetch the visible text from any element by element.getText().

[image]

Also, its important to understand that why the value to Identifier should be given to the only required objects.

For instance, If you want to identify elements like Btn Previous or Btn next then one need to avoid assigning Identifier value to Header or View(parent object). I find that ,providing value to parent suppress the Identifier for child elements.

[image]